# I've downloaded the extension 'Markdown Pdf', but it does not show up in my command palette

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is pretty basic, no code to show. I downloaded the extension, and it shows as downloaded, but when I search for its function in the command palette, it's not there.

Comment: Does it require a reload of vscode?  Some extensions do.

Comment: I don't think so, I've closed and opened the app multiple times

Comment: Doesn't sound like an actively maintained extension, https://github.com/yzane/vscode-markdown-pdf/issues So you might have to find another.

Comment: Hm. Thanks @LexLi, do you know of one?